# What Happens When Font Awesome Kit Free Plan Limit is Reached?

Tags: font-awesome

In their [pricing page](https://fontawesome.com/plans), Font Awesome free version now (March 2020) shows a limit of **10k pageviews per month.** What happens when your site reaches that limit? Will fonts stop showing? I can't seem to find the answer after Googling. Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you be asking Font Awesome customer service this question?

Comment: if you are serving it from your own servers, there is no page view limits. refer - https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome/issues/220

Comment: They've just started enforcement of this limit for npm - they didn't give us enough warning to do anything about it so we're abandoning font awesome for alternatives now.

Answer (score 2):

Update email I just received from Font Awesome:

> Starting in September 2023, we will begin emailing folks who are nearing (or exceeding) their Font Awesome Free pageview limits. As a reminder, all Free accounts include 10,000 pageviews per month. Limits reset on the first of each month.
> These emails are meant to increase transparency around your account and how it's being used. At this time, we will NOT be shutting off accounts who exceed their pageviews limits.
> Usage data can be seen on your accounts page, or from within Font Awesome Kits. Please reach out to hello@fontawesome.com with any questions. (Pageviews do not apply to icon downloads or for those self-hosting Font Awesome.)

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing the answer, the icons continue to be displayed after reaching the limit.

Comment: They've just started enforcement of this limit. We've had sites stop working because of too much bandwidth being used.

Answer (score 0):

Those limits only apply if you are using one of the services that Font Awesome is paying the bandwidth for. If you are serving it from your own servers there are no page view limits.